# What are the difference between JPA's EntityManager and Hibernate's First level caching?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Recently I faced a F-to-F interview in a company.
Interviewer just asked me the following question:

> What are the differences between JPA's EntityManager and Hibernate's First level caching?
>   Please explain with suitable example.

Comment: so how did you answer?

Comment: I just define the First level caching and entity manager.
But He again asked me that what are the differences?
I am not able to tell him the difference... @ScaryWombat

Comment: It means both terms are same? @Desorder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate itself implemented JPA through the Hibernate Annotations and Hibernate EntityManager libraries (or flavors), which are built on top of the Hibernate Core libraries. Hibernate EntityManager is a complete implementation of JPA and it follows the JPA lifecycle

JPA is like an interface which is implemented by other ORM's and these ORM's are act as a vendor for this..
So, there is no question of difference...
and for to learn more you can go through this link.

**https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_caching**

Comment: It means both are same. But technology change.

Comment: one is like an interface and other was its implementation...JPA runs over hibernate

Comment: No, they are not the same. Even because you can have JPA without having Hibernate. Hibernate is only one of the many JPA implementations around. To name others, OpenJPA, EclipseLink and others.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually hard to point the differences between those two as it's the same as asking the differences between a banana and an apple. Here are the definition of both.

**Entity Manager**

> The EntityManager API is used to access a database in a particular unit of work. It is used to create and remove persistent entity instances, to find entities by their primary key identity, and to query over all entities. This interface is similar to the Session in Hibernate.

from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/architecture.html

**First Level Hibernate cache**

> It's a cache facility attached to the Hibernate session to speed up data retrieval.

Here is a good article about it that cover some basic aspects.
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/01/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/

So, I would list some of the differences as:

- Entity Manager is part of the JPA specification (which consequently is standard across the whole Java EE platform.) to perform database access via managed entities.
- Hibernate First level cache is a cache facility to return cached **hibernate entities** (please note the bold as hibernate entities might not be the same JPA entities).